# Why is there a small circle on my css dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

A small circle appears on my dropdown menu and I can't figure out why...
Same for all browsers.

Dropdown menu can be found here http://www.chatroom.guru
Login and see the dropdownmenu - The circle appears on the second listed li.
Login: admin - test123

Hope you can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to apply a css rule  *list-style: none;* to your **ul**  this rule remove the circle that appeared.

I hope I can help you, greetings.

Comment: Greetings!! , I hope will be helpful